# java app hangs when not run from command-line

Tags: java, windows

In Windows 7, when i double-click my .jar-file, the app runs partially and then hangs. When run using `java -jar MyFile.jar` or  `javaw -jar MyFile.jar` on the command-line it runs just fine though. It also runs fine on linux mint when using the GUI to run it. Is there any way i can debug this? (preferably using eclipse)

**Edit:**

Ok. I might have narrowed it down. When i write a simple test app:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class MyDebug {
    private static void err(String message){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,message);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        err("test");
    }
```

The program runs fine in the command-line using javaw, but when trying to execute from the desktop java alerts me that it "Could not find the main class:MyDebug. Program will exit."

**Edit:**

I might have narrowed it down even further now; when launching from the desktop the 32-bit version of javaw is used, and when launching from the command-line the 64-bit version is used.

**SOLVED**
I solved the problem by going to programs and features in the control panel, uninstalling java and reinstalling it. Can't answer my own post yet though

Comment: Do double-click and command line run the same JRE? Do you see any exceptions?

Comment: What does it mean "runs partially"? Which part works and which one does not? Do you have any log files? Probably you can see exceptions there.

Comment: @home I don't know if the different ways of executing uses different JRE:s, how do I check this?

Comment: @user1143825 As far as i can see i don't have $JAVA_HOME set and $PATH doesn't include a path to the java executables. I checked this by going to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables; did I overlook something?

Comment: @remuladgryta, open command prompt and type `echo %PATH%` end `echo %JAVA_HOME%`

Comment: @AlexR by runs partially I mean: some the gui shows up, the backend doesn't work.

%PATH% includes system32, wich has a java.exe and a javaw.exe

Comment: That will be enough for you. However you really need to figure why the application did not run with 32bit JRE.  Out Of Memory?

Answer (score 4):

@Benny Han gave me a good idea (+1). Try to run `javaw -jar MyFile.jar` instead of `java -jar MyFile.jar` from command prompt. 
I believe that your application will hung up exactly as it happens when you are running it by double clicking on jar file. In this case the possible cause is using STDIN or STDOUT in your program. Remember: they do not exist when using `javaw`.

Comment: I figured as much, and commented any lines that uses them, still the same behavior though

Answer (score 3):

in your windows environment, check the java command and the javaw command. When you double click the jar file, it's the javaw command runs the jar file. I guess it maybe because you have more than one jre installed.

Comment: I this case really check which JRE are you using in both cases. I think, guys are probably right:  probably your PATH variable is not configured correctly and you have several JREs installed on your machine and using different JREs when running from command prompt and from  click.

Comment: How do I check what JRE I'm using when launching using the different methods?

Answer (score 1):

Try launching via a script..

```
echo "started from %cd%"
set scriptroot=%~dp0%

java -version
echo %path%

java -jar %scriptroot%\MyFile.jar

echo "press any key  to continue"
pause
```

Then come back with java version, exception etc.

Comment: Your script run with `@ehco off`:

"started from C:\Users\remuladgryta\Desktop"
java version "1.7.0_02"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_02-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)
java -jar C:\Users\remuladgryta\Desktop\\MyFile.jar
"press any key  to continue"
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: (It was meant to debug). remove the echo from  echo  java -jar  line with 'java -jar' .

Comment: Using your script i get no exceptions at all and the program runs fine